# Analyze EPS metadata - Distinguish between Freehand EPS and Illustrator EPS

Tags: metadata, adobe-illustrator

I want to analyze a few thousand EPS files and sort them according to their application in which they have been created (in my case Freehand or Illustrator).

I know that the the information is stored in the file header (%%Creator), but how can I analyze it thoughout all files?

I am looking for a way to analyze the files and to give me a txt or csv file...

**I already tried the following:**

- Windows Explorer --> shows lots of properties, but not the %%Creator
- Adobe Bridge --> shows file metadata, but only of single files
- Adobe Bridge, [MetaData Script](http://www.ps-bridge-scripts.talktalk.net/) (See the Bridge section -- Extract Metadata) --> the script should export all metadata, but doesn't do it's job for all files...
- pdfinfo.exe --> part of [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), I assumed, if it can analyze PDF files, it may also analyze EPS, but does't...
- Ghostscript --> I searched Google, but did not find a solution
- ImageMagick  --> I searched Google, but did not find a solution
- ExifTool --> although it seems to be powerful, I could not manage to get the information intended

I am happy for any help!

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful support!
I asked the same question at StackOverflow, but got the proposal to post the question here... 
[http://stackoverflow.com/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766305/analyze-eps-metadata-distinguish-between-freehand-eps-and-illustrator-eps)
My intention is not to find THE TOOL, but instead find A WAY HOW TO achive my request.... 
best regards Hape